# How to get elevation from Google Earth in Python

Tags: python, google-earth-engine

I'm new with the Google Earth Engine. I'm trying to get the elevation of 3 nodes in a list [[lan, lat],[lan, lat],[lan, lat]] and save it in a variable `elevation`. Can anybody show me how or suggest a good answer?

```
dataset = ee.Image('CGIAR/SRTM90_V4');
elevation = dataset.select('elevation');
slope = ee.Terrain.slope(elevation);
elevation_list=[....some long tat values]
elevatioval=Map.setCenter(elevation_list);
```

the output should be like this

```
[evation1,elevation2,elevation3...]
```

Comment: there is an answer on how to extract pixel values by point by point >> [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/265392/extracting-pixel-values-by-points-and-converting-to-table-in-google-earth-engine)